# How do I convert the following cURL query to Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, curl

I have a piece of cURL code as follows:

```
curl -k --tlsv1.0 <url>
```

I can't seem to convert this exactly to a Node.JS query.

**Note:** I need the tag `--tlsv1.0`.

Comment: It sounds like you have tried something to achieve it. If we had your code, adapted to be a [mcve], we could debug it and provide you with the solution and an explanation for any error you are encountering instead of starting from scratch. Please [edit] your question to provide us with the necessary code and any error message that pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [node-libcurl](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl)

You can set ssl version

```
Curl.sslversion = {
    DEFAULT : 0,
    TLSv1 : 1,
    SSLv2 : 2,
    SSLv3 : 3
};
```